# CloudHopper Server sending MO to connected client

Tags: java, smpp

I have a project where we are using ArdanStudios smppclient to connect to an SMPPServer. We can send messages to the SMPP Server and they get delivered to the handset. When the hand set replies or sends to the shortcode we do get a received message event but the message text is blank.

We are using CloudHopper internally to simulate the SMPP Server, I want to confirm that there isn't a problem on our end when receiving messages but I can not figure out a  way to simulate an MO (mobile originated) message sent from Cloudhopper server to our connected ArdanClient. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions in one Pal.  I suggest you break it up.  For the first one basically you have to override the firePduRequestReceived methos of class DefaultSmppSessionHandler:

```
  @Override
public PduResponse firePduRequestReceived(PduRequest pduRequest) {

    PduResponse response = pduRequest.createResponse();

    if (pduRequest.getCommandId() == SmppConstants.CMD_ID_DELIVER_SM) {
       processMO(pduRequest);
    }        
    return response;
}

private void processsMO(PduRequest request){
    DeliverSm mo = (DeliverSm) request;
    int length = mo.getShortMessageLength();
    Address sourceAddr = mo.getSourceAddress();
    Address destAddr = mo.getDestAddress();
    byte[] shortMessage = mo.getShortMessage();
    String sms= new String(shortMessage);

    //Do Something....

}
```